# Does NonlinearModelFit result stores FitResiduals?

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting, nonlinear

I fits a long data series with a complex model by `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
fitnlm = NonlinearModelFit[...]
```

Then I can use `fitnlm["BestFitParameters"]` to get parameters, use `fitnlm["Response"]` to view original data. By the way, `Length@fitnlm["Response"]` gives 3603 so it is not a very long data series. However, when I try to run

```
fitnlm["FitResiduals"]
```

It seems that the mathematica core keeps running forever and didn't return an answer. The `fitnlm["FitResiduals"]` should have same Length as `fitnlm["Response"]`. Is it because that FitResiduals is not stored in `fitnlm` and will be calculated every time I run fitnlm["FitResiduals"]? But calculating FitResiduals should not be more difficult than run `fitnlm = NonlinearModelFit[...]`, the later takes several seconds while the former takes forever, what's wrong?

Comment: This can't be answered without a complete minimal example.